# Riemann-Hurwitz formula for curves without schemes?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Is it possible to learn the proof and statement of the Riemann-Hurwitz formula for curves in Algebraic geometry without knowing schemes? If so: any good references? Thanks

Comment: See the answer of Steven Gubkin here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/99292/question-regarding-riemann-hurwitz-formula-proof

Comment: Over arbitrary ground field and with a separability hypothesis, you don't need the language of schemes.  See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/174189) by Georges Elencwajg.

Comment: Yes, it's definitely possible. One reference is Silverman's *The Arithmetic Of Elliptic Curves*, section II.5, Theorem 5.9.